# How to use pow function in C programming particularly in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

I am trying to execute following program in eclipse

[image]

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int a, base, power;

    printf("\nBase:");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &base);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("\nExponent:");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &power);
    fflush(stdin);

    a = pow(base, power);

    printf("\nAnswer: %d", a);
    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
    getch();
}
```

the output to the above program should be as follows

Base :
Exponent :
Answer:

but I am getting different output

[image]

```
Base: 2

Exponent: 2

Enter base value: 2

Enter exponent value: 2

The exponent value of 2 is 4
Answer: 0
```

as you can see the output is asking me to enter the base and exponent values two times where's it should ask only once.

How to disable this?

Comment: You need to paste in the text of your code and output, not use screenshots. If someone wants to run your code to help you, they can't do that very easily from an image.

Comment: Never ever `fflush()` stdin! You can only flush output streams.

Comment: It looks as if the source code and the output belonged to two different prigrans (or at least two different stages of the same program).

Comment: Delete code lines 23 and 28. And then run the program again.

Comment: @FelixG: Microsoft defines the behavior of flushing `stdin`, so it is proper code when targeting a Microsoft Windows system with Microsoft tools.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It still remains undefined behavior according to the C standard, and should therefore not be used. The only reason you can get away with it when using MS tools is because it's an implementation of something similar to, but not quite compatible with, C. In other words: Microsofts compiler is a non-conforming C++ compiler, and their standard library is also not conforming to the C standard.

Comment: @FelixG: “It still remains undefined behavior according to the C standard, and should therefore not be used”: That is a misunderstanding of the C standard. Using network connections is also undefined by the C standard, but you would not say nobody should use those. The C standard defines only a core language. It is designed and intended to be extended. Defining the behavior of flushing `stdin` does not make a compiler non-conforming to the C standard; it is a conforming extension.

Comment: @EricPostpischil IMHO calling `fflush()` on an output stream isn't quite the same as using network connections (because the latter just doesn't exist in the standard library). That being said, you are correct in that defining undefined behavior is permitted by the C standard, even though it results in people writing non-portable code. However, Microsofts implementation is still non-conforming for a variety of other reasons (like some examples where their library makes perfectly defined behavior undefined, which is 100% definitely not permitted by the standard)

Comment: @FelixG: How would a programmer know what is acceptable in your view? Can they use inline assembly? If not, how do they access architecture-specific features? When a programmer is targeting a Windows system and wants to discard all input typed by the user so far, what do you recommend they use? Can they use GCC’s decimal floating-point types? Can they access hardware registers through volatile objects? Can they use GCC's function and variable attributes? Can they use GCC's popcount built-in? If not, how do you recommend a programmer write code to count bits that will compile to optimal code?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Any programmer is free to do what ever they want, and of course i'm not the one making the rules here (the ISO/IEC 9899 committee is). But i still stand by the point that there is an important difference between implementation-specific features/extensions which aren't even mentioned by the standard, and things like flushing stdin, which is explicitly mentioned to cause undefined behavior. Also, as long as someone doesn't state their specific platform and compiler (like in this case), telling them not to flush stdin is the only sensible thing to do.

Comment: @FelixG: Re “explicitly mentioned to cause undefined behavior”: When the standard says something has undefined behavior, that is not adding a rule that using the thing has behavior that is not and cannot be defined. It is stating **only** that the C standard does not impose any requirements. That includes not imposing any requirements on whether implementations define it or not or whether programs use it or not. It is simply the standard saying it is not defining it as part of the core language, not that it is something programmers should avoid.

Comment: @FelixG: “Never ever `fflush()` stdin!” conflicts with “Any programmer is free to do what ever they want”. I ask again: how would a programmer know what is acceptable in your view? Tell us what the criteria are that you recommend for choosing what to use and what not to use. Are the GCC extensions that the C standard says are “undefined” things that people should “never ever” use? (By the way, `conio.h` is not a standard header; its use in the code in the question clues us in to the target.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil So you would tell inexperienced programmers that it's okay to define main as `float main(void*)` just because there might be some implementation, where that would be acceptable? If they don't state their specific platform and compiler, we can't (and shouldn't) assume that their code is correct, just because there are situations where it might be (especially when they state that code **doesn't work**).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214265/discussion-between-felix-g-and-eric-postpischil).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you should fix in your code:

- Remove the `getch();` line after the return. It won't be executed and you should be getting a compiler warning about this line. Now you can also remove `#include<conio.h>` as you don't need it.
- You `fflush()` stdin or stdout (as pointed out in the comments).

The resulting code runs just fine and produces the expected output. You can check it out here: https://onlinegdb.com/S1LLp9GoU

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int
main ()
{
  int a, base, power;

  printf ("\nBase:");
  scanf ("%d", &base);

  printf ("\nExponent:");
  scanf ("%d", &power);

  a = pow (base, power);

  printf ("\nAnswer: %d", a);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!.. Got it... code is now working as expected.